# C# Initializing a Multi-dimensional array with multiple 1D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to initialize a two-dimensional array using two existing 1D arrays. Obviously, if we know the values of these arrays, we can initialize it like such:

```
float[,] my2DArray = new float{{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

However, if I try to initialize the array with variables like this:

```
float[] a = {1,2};
float[] b = {3,4};
float[,] my2DArray = new float{a,b};
```

then I get an error *"A nested array initializer is expected."* 
I'm guessing maybe this has something to do with the compiler not knowing the dimensions of the array since it won't be allocated until runtime.

So, is there any way I can work around this to do this sort of array assignment? I am targeting .NET 4.0.

Comment: do you know how many arrays there will be like a,b at compile time ? you can't do such assignment but you can populate your array using a loop.

Comment: @Selman22 No, I receive `a` and `b` from another function, and they will have variable lengths (though the lengths of `a` and `b` will be the same as each other). I was trying to avoid using a loop to populate if at all possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to initialize the array yourself.  You can get a performance improvement and shorter code than looping by using [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but can't do an inline initialization directly:

```
float[] a = {1,2};
float[] b = {3,4};
float[,] my2DArray = new float[a.Length, 2];

int len = a.Length * sizeof(float);
Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, my2DArray, 0, len);
Buffer.BlockCopy(b, 0, my2DArray, len, len);
```

Note that you'll have to guarantee that the source arrays are the same length for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] a = { 1, 2 };
float[] b = { 3, 4 };

float[,] my2DArray = new float[a.Length, b.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++) 
         my2DArray[i, j] = new float[][] { a, b }[i][j];
```